# Weights of CNN model go to really small values and after NaN

Tags: python, keras

I am not able to understand the reason why the weights of following model are going smaller and smaller until `NaN` during training.

The model is the following:

```
def initialize_embedding_matrix(embedding_matrix):
    embedding_layer = Embedding(
        input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0],
        output_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[1],
        weights=[embedding_matrix],
        trainable=True)
    return embedding_layer

def get_divisor(x):
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x), axis=-1))


def similarity(a, b):
    numerator = K.sum(a * b, axis=-1)
    denominator = get_divisor(a) * get_divisor(b)
    denominator = K.maximum(denominator, K.epsilon())
    return numerator / denominator


def max_margin_loss(positive, negative):
    loss_matrix = K.maximum(0.0, 1.0 + negative - Reshape((1,))(positive))
    loss = K.sum(loss_matrix, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return loss


def warp_loss(X):
    z, positive_entity, negatives_entities = X
    positiveSim = Lambda(lambda x: similarity(x[0], x[1]), output_shape=(1,), name="positive_sim")([z, positive_entity])
    z_reshaped = Reshape((1, z.shape[1].value))(z)
    negativeSim = Lambda(lambda x: similarity(x[0], x[1]), output_shape=(negatives_titles.shape[1].value, 1,), name="negative_sim")([z_reshaped, negatives_entities])
    loss = Lambda(lambda x: max_margin_loss(x[0], x[1]), output_shape=(1,), name="max_margin")([positiveSim, negativeSim])
    return loss

def mean_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred - 0 * y_true)

def build_nn_model():
    wl, tl = load_vector_lookups()
    embedded_layer_1 = initialize_embedding_matrix(wl)
    embedded_layer_2 = initialize_embedding_matrix(tl)

    sequence_input_1 = Input(shape=(_NUMBER_OF_LENGTH,), dtype='int32',name="text")
    sequence_input_positive = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name="positive")
    sequence_input_negatives = Input(shape=(10,), dtype='int32', name="negatives")

    embedded_sequences_1 = embedded_layer_1(sequence_input_1)
    embedded_sequences_positive = Reshape((tl.shape[1],))(embedded_layer_2(sequence_input_positive))
    embedded_sequences_negatives = embedded_layer_2(sequence_input_negatives)

    conv_step1 = Convolution1D(
        filters=1000,
        kernel_size=5,
        activation="tanh",
        name="conv_layer_mp",
        padding="valid")(embedded_sequences_1)

    conv_step2 = GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="max_pool_mp")(conv_step1)
    conv_step3 = Activation("tanh")(conv_step2)
    conv_step4 = Dropout(0.2, name="dropout_mp")(conv_step3)
    z = Dense(wl.shape[1], name="predicted_vec")(conv_step4) # activation="linear"

    loss = warp_loss([z, embedded_sequences_positive, embedded_sequences_negatives])
    model = Model(
        inputs=[sequence_input_1, sequence_input_positive, sequence_input_negatives],
        outputs=[loss]
        )
    model.compile(loss=mean_loss, optimizer=Adam())
    return model

model = build_nn_model()
x, y_real, y_fake = load_x_y()
    X_train = {
    'text': x_train,
    'positive': y_real_train,
    'negatives': y_fake_train
}

model.fit(x=X_train,  y=np.ones(len(x_train)), batch_size=10, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, epochs=10)
```

To describe the model a bit:

- I have two pre-trained embeddings(`wl`,`tl`) and I initialize the Keras embeddings with these values.
- There are 3 inputs. The `sequence_input_1` has integers as input (indexes of words. ex. `[42, 32 .., 4]`). On them `sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=_NUMBER_OF_LENGTH)` is used to have fixed length. `sequence_input_positive` which is an integer of the positive output and `sequence_input_negatives` which are N random negative outputs (10 in the code above) for each example.
- max_margin_loss measures the difference between the `cosinus_similarity(positive_example, sequence_input_1)` and`cosinus_similarity(negative_example[i], sequence_input_1)` and the Adam optimizer is used to minimize loss.

While training this model even with only 20 data points the weights in the `Convolution1D` and `Dense` goes to NaN. If I add more data points the embedding weights go to NaN too. I can observe that as the model runs the weights are going smaller and smaller until they go to NaN. Something noticable also is that the loss does not go to NaN. When weights reach NaN, the loss goes to zero.

I am unable to find what is going wrong.

This is what I tried until now:

- I have seen that people are using stochastic gradient descent when hinge loss is used. Using `SGD` optimizer didn't change something in the behavior here.
- changed the number of batch size. No change in behavior.
- checked input data not to have `nan` values.
- normalized the input matrix (pre-trained data) for embedding with `np.linalg.norm`
- transform  pre-trained matrix from `float64` to `float32`

Do you see anything strange in the architecture of the model? If not: I am unable to find a way to debug the architecture in order to understand why weights are going smaller and smaller till reach NaN. Is there some steps people are using when they notice this kind of behaviour?

**Edit**:

By using `trainable=False` in the Embeddings this behaviour of `nan` weights is NOT observed, and the training seems to have smooth results. However I want the embeddings to be trainable. So why this behavior when the embeddings are trainable??

**Edit2**:

Using `trainable=True` and by uniformly randomly initializing the weights `embeddings_initializer='uniform'` the training is smooth. So the reason happening is my word embeddings. I have checked my pre-trained word embeddings and there are no `NaN` values. I have also normalized them in case this was causing it but no lack. Cant think anything else why these specific weights are giving this behaviour.

**Edit3**:

It seems that what causing this was that a lot of rows from one of the Embeddings trained in gensim where all zeros. ex.

```
[0.2, 0.1, .. 0.3],
[0.0, 0.0, .. 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, .. 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, .. 0.0],
[0.2, 0.1, .. 0.1]
```

It was not so easy to find it as the dimension of the embeddings where really big.

I am leaving this question open in case someone comes up with something similar or wants to answer the question  asked above: "Is there some steps people are using when they notice this kind of behaviour?"

Comment: There are a lot of missing things in your code. Many functions we cannot see what they do. You should, though, check your activations, and make sure that the outputs of the last layer are compatible (in the same range) with the true data.

Comment: @DanielMöller I have updated a bit the code. The only that I am not providing is the `load_vector_lookups()` which is nothing more that for loading the initialization of the embedding layers, and the load of the training data. Why it should be in the same range the outputs of last layer and true data? I am not even using actually the `y` as in the loss function (`mean_loss`) `y` is multiplied with `0`.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. `y_pred` is not multiplied by zero. Only `y_real` which actually does not exist. What I am trying is to minimize `1 - cos_sim(text,positive) + cos_sim(text,negative)`, which is a max_margin as far as i understand. The way i implement the loss was inspired by https://github.com/maciejkula/triplet_recommendations_keras

Comment: My mistake, sorry. (Erasing that comment to avoid misleading and other comments about this mistake).

Comment: Are these embeddings trainable?

Comment: I pretrained using gensim. And from the code it can be seen that they are trainable in this model `trainable=True`. They are also reaching to small numbers and in the end go to `nan`

Comment: @DanielMöller taking into consideration your question if the embeddings are trainable, i changed it to not be trainable. I have updated my question.

Comment: This line looks odd: `K.mean(y_pred - 0 * y_true)`. Multiplying with zero is never good...

Answer (score 1):

By your edits, it got a little easier to find the problem.

Those zeros passed unchanged to the `warp_loss` function. 
The part that went through the convolution remained unchanged at first, because any filters multiplied by zero result in zero, and the default bias initializer is also `'zeros'`. The same idea applies to the dense (filters * 0 = 0 and bias initializer = 'zeros')

That reached this line: `return numerator / denominator` and caused an error (division by zero)

It's a common practice I've seen in many codes to add `K.epsilon()` to avoid this:

```
return numerator / (denominator + K.epsilon())
```

Comment: If you see in the `warp_loss` I already have  `K.max(denominator, K.epsilon)`